# why does my emacs whitespace mode add "Â" to my buffer?

Tags: terminal, emacs, character-encoding

I'm using Putty to ssh into a RedHat box, and I'm running GNU emacs inside the putty ssh window.

When I turn on whitespace-mode using M-x whitespace mode, I notice I see a "Â" before each space or tab character:

```
Â·Â·Â·Â·thisÂ·isÂ·someÂ·spaces$
Â»       thisÂ·isÂ·aÂ·tab$
```

has anyone seen this before? I suspect its because of my terminal settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Â·` in latin1 is the byte sequence `c2 b7`. That same byte sequence interpreted in UTF-8 is the character `·`. So what's happening is that Emacs believes your terminal displays UTF-8 (Unicode) but your terminal actually displays latin1.

PuTTY supports UTF-8, so the easiest solution is to tell it to use UTF-8, at least when connecting to this host. As an added benefit, you'll be able to use characters outside latin1.